# use a character for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing

I want to use a character  in for loop but I can't because I'm using ginput function and it's possible to first and end pixel in for loop changed by every mouse click I cant use an exact pixel it's my error when run my code.

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
A=imread('peppers.png');
C=imshow(A);
F=rgb2gray(A);
figure,imshow(F)
B=ginput(4)
a=min(B);
b=max(B);
a1=a(1)
a2=a(2)
b1=b(1)-a(1)
b2=b(2)-a(2)
for i=a1:a1+b1
    for j=a2:a2+b2
       F(j,i)=0;
    end
end
figure,imshow(F)
```

Comment: I recommend to read the MATLAB documentation about Indexing. It can save you a lot of work. `F(a1:a1+b1,a2:a2+b2)=0` fully replaces the two loops and is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you get from `input` are slightly off the full integer. Use `B-round(B)` and you see the error.

To fix it, use `round`

```
B=round(ginput(4))
```

The error message was really curious

> Attempted to access F(142,162); index must be a
>   positive integer or logical.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: The comment you deleted was right, you can still break it simply clicking the area outside the image.